# Why does `align` break `tikz` node placement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to put some marks in the document and place desciptions of these marks in the margin area, one below another.

It works fine, however if I place a mark inside `align` environment corresponding node is vertically misplaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\note#1{%
  \textcolor{red}{!}%
  \ifmeasuring@\else % do nothing during the measuring phase
    \tikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@note}
            {\coordinate (pos) at (0,0-|current page marginpar area.north west);}
            {\coordinate (pos) at (note.south west);}
        \node (note) [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text=red] at (pos) {#1};
        \draw[red] (note.south west) rectangle (note.north east);
    \endtikzpicture
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
Some text, more\note{text 1st} text, even more text.
\begin{displaymath}
    a+b+c =\note{math 1st} d+e+f = g+h
\end{displaymath}
Some text, more\note{text 2nd} text, even more text.
\begin{align}
    a+b+c &=\note{align 1st} d+e+f \\
    &= g\note{align 2nd}+h
\end{align}
Some text, more\note{text 3rd} text, even more text.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Column 1&Column 2\note{tabu 1st}&Column3\\\hline
        Cell 1&Cell 2&Cell 3\\\hline
        Cell 4&Cell 5\note{tabu 2nd}&Cell 6\\\hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{center}
Some text, more\note{text 4th} text, even more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

The same thing occurs if I use `tabu` tabular environment. Meanwhile `displaymath` and `tabular` do no harm.

What is the reason?

**Edit: Included `tabu` in MWE**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know, but probably the space you see is reserved and not filled because `align` does two passes over the contents, throwing away the result of the first pass, only keeping the measurements for sizing the columns in the second phase. You can work around this by setting the picture only in the final typesetting phase, not when `amsmath` measures the parts of the display:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\note#1{%
  \textcolor{red}{!}%
  \ifmeasuring@\else % do nothing during the measuring phase
    \tikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@note}
            {\coordinate (pos) at (0,0-|current page marginpar area.north west);}
            {\coordinate (pos) at (note.south west);}
        \node (note) [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text=red] at (pos) {#1};
        \draw[red] (note.south west) rectangle (note.north east);
    \endtikzpicture
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Some text, more\note{text 1st} text, even more text.
\begin{displaymath}
    a+b+c =\note{math 1st} d+e+f = g+h
\end{displaymath}
Some text, more\note{text 2nd} text, even more text.
\begin{align}
    a+b+c &=\note{math 2nd} d+e+f \\
    &= g+h
\end{align}
Some text, more\note{text 3rd} text, even more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Halfway there - works fine for `align`, fails for `tabu`. I didn't originally include `tabu` in mwe, because I thought misplacement had the same origin as for `align`. Please take a look at updated example.

Comment: @Paul Also `tabu` does multiple passes over the material, but, as far as I know, it doesn't provide a mechanism similar to `\ifmeasuring@`

Comment: After 4 hrs of trials-and-errors I'm just out of ideas...  Is there really no workaround? It seemed so trival at first...

Comment: @Paul I abandoned trying to tame `tabu` in this respect time ago.